# Visual Studio Setup Projects: Cleartype

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, vdproj

I use a Visual Studio Setup project to create an installer for some assemblies. However, the fonts the installer uses are always aliased, and don't appear to be the Windows standard.

[image]
<sub>(source: [paulstovell.com](http://www.paulstovell.com/get/magellan/installer-welcome.png))</sub>

(Note that the installer text uses aliased text rendering, but the window title uses ClearType)

Is there any way to update the MSI to use ClearType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the short answer is no.

However you could edit the generated MSI with an editor like [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx) which allows to change the fonts families or sizes, but not anything close to enabling ClearType as it is controlled by Windows.

With that said, according to [this](http://codeka.com/blogs/index.php/2008/10/01/installers-and-cleartype) it seems WIX does support ClearType. Anybody who started with VS installer eventually had their one caveat which made them switch to WIX, NSIS or a commercial solution. Yours might be the most unique motive :)